# Bulk data API: How to Avoid Upserts

Tags: data-loader, bestpractice, bulk-api, largedatavolumes, bulk

I'm working on an daily integration of about 5 million records (file delta's is not an option).

[Best practices for large data volumes](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/cce/ldv_deployments/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf) recommends avoiding upserts.

The only alternative solution I can really see to do so would be to pull down the entire database (which is possible) and check it against the datafile to determine which records should be updated and which should be inserted.  If the data ever gets larger than what can fit in memory this process with get even slower and more complex.

I guess I'm looking for some validation (preferably from real world experience) on if I would actually see any meaningful gains from avoiding upserts?

Comment: looking at the docs, they suggest doing the most efficient operation which was inserts > updates > upserts, but it doesn't seem like they rule out upserts. Perhaps it might be worth giving upserts a try to confirm whether they would be a performance hit? If there isn't one, you're good, and if there is you know time spent researching options for improving performance would be worth it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upserts are slower than the relevant operations, but the actual time used depends on your strategy. Inserts are faster than upserts on all new records, updates are faster than upserts on all existing records, and mixed upserts are slower than inserts and updates combined.

The difference can indeed be about 100% in time (double). The difference in time for upserts that are entirely existing or entirely new records is much smaller, around 10%.

If you expect that 90% or more of your records will already exist daily, upsert might be more efficient after all.  If there's lots of churn (deletes and inserts), the query then update strategy might be better.

Your best option would be to use the replication API every hour or so to maintain an offline database of Salesforce Ids to your unique indexes. This would let you perform updates much faster and determine new records; you could then run updates on known existing records, and upsert the inserts to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Hadn't even considered the replication API.  Thanks!